# How to list all files with certain extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

Is it possible to list all files who have a certain extension in the sidebar in VS Code?

i.e. all files with .js extension?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code [has a `files.exclude` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). In theory, you should be able to exclude everything and then override that setting for `.js` files exclusively. That would look something like this:

```
{
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/*": true,
     "**/*.js": false,
   },
 }
```

Unfortunately the expected behavior does not align with the actual results, but there is an [open issue regarding this exact feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869).